# Material UI with Login Template with React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm brand new to Material UI. I am currently trying to implement it into my project. Unfortunately, it's not cooperating. I think I am putting in everything right, but because I have never used MUI before, I am not sure. Can someone please help me figure out where the error is? I have tried multiple times, putting in the code I had before I tried to implement MUI. Thank you!

I will include the code before I tried to implement MUI, and after. The first is before MUI implementation. The last block of code is my Auth.jsx file.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login({ updateToken, toggleView }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleUsername = (e) => setUsername(e.target.value);
  const handlePassword = (e) => setPassword(e.target.value);

  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const fetchResults = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/user/`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }),
      });
      const json = await fetchResults.json();
      if (!json.user || !json.sessionToken) {
        alert(json.message);
        return;
      }
      updateToken(json.sessionToken);
      history.push("/home");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='signin'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type='username'
            onChange={handleUsername}
            name='username'
            placeholder='Username'
            required
            value={username}
            className='signin__input'
          />
          <input
            type='password'
            onChange={handlePassword}
            name='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            type='password'
            required
            value={password}
            className='signin__input'
          />
          <button className='login__button' type='submit'>
            Login
          </button>
        </form>{" "}
        <p className='signin__toggle' onClick={() => history.push("./signup")}>
          Don't have an account? Sign up here.{" "}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

function Copyright(props) {
  return (
    <Typography
      variant='body2'
      color='text.secondary'
      align='center'
      {...props}
    >
      {"Copyright © "}
      <Link color='inherit' href='https://courtney-downs.web.app/'>
        Courtney Downs Portfolio
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const theme = createTheme();

export default function Login2({ updateToken, toggleView }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleUsername = (e) => setUsername(e.target.value);
  const handlePassword = (e) => setPassword(e.target.value);

  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const fetchResults = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/user/`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }),
      });
      const json = await fetchResults.json();
      if (!json.user || !json.sessionToken) {
        alert(json.message);
        return;
      }
      updateToken(json.sessionToken);
      history.push("/home");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container component='main' maxWidth='xs'>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: "secondary.main" }}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component='h1' variant='h5'>
            Sign in
          </Typography>
          <Box
            component='form'
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            noValidate
            sx={{ mt: 1 }}
          >
            <TextField
              margin='normal'
              required
              fullWidth
              id='username'
              label='Username'
              name='username'
              autoComplete='username'
              value={username}
              onChange={handleUsername}
              autoFocus
            />
            <TextField
              margin='normal'
              required
              fullWidth
              name='password'
              label='Password'
              type='password'
              id='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={handlePassword}
              autoComplete='current-password'
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value='remember' color='primary' />}
              label='Remember me'
            />
            <Button
              type='submit'
              fullWidth
              variant='contained'
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs>
                <Link href='#' variant='body2'>
                  Forgot password?
                </Link>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Link onClick={toggleView} variant='body2'>
                  {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <Copyright sx={{ mt: 8, mb: 4 }} />
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Login2 from "./Login2";
import Signup from "./Signup";

export default function Auth({ sessionToken, updateToken }) {
  const [loginShowing, setLoginShowing] = useState(true);

  const toggleView = () => setLoginShowing(!loginShowing);

  return (
    <div>
      {loginShowing ? (
        <Login2
          token={sessionToken}
          updateToken={updateToken}
          toggleView={toggleView}
        />
      ) : (
        <Signup
          updateToken={updateToken}
          token={sessionToken}
          toggleView={toggleView}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: not cooperating? you didn't mention any error ... please elaborate a bit more or put your code in codesandbox

Comment: please explain whats your goal and what's your attempt?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.